# Label on vector - tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a line segment and a vector which is orthogonal to it. I would to add a label to the vector, e.g., x or y. Is it possible to do this via a parameter to the below code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,2) node (yaxis) [above] {$y$}
    |- (3,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
\draw (-1,3) coordinate (a_1) -- (3,0) coordinate (a_2);

\tikzAngleOfLine(a_1)(a_2){\angle};
\draw[black,->] (a_2) -- ++ (\angle+90:0.3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\draw[black,->] (a_2) -- ++ (\angle+90:0.3) node[midway,above] {label};` is how I would do it.

Comment: Nice! But it falls on the vector's arrow. I mean the label "touches" the vector.

Comment: You may control the distance. E.g., `\draw[black,->] (a_2) -- ++ (\angle+90:0.3) node[midway,above=1cm] {label};`

Comment: or `node[midway,above,sloped]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is to replace your last line with

```
\draw[black,->] (a_2) -- ++ (\angle+90:0.3) node[midway,above,sloped] {label};
```

I can't help but notice some additional optimizations.  First, the macro `\tikzAngleOfLine` does nothing other than expand `\tikz@AngleOfLine`, so you might have well just `\def`'d `\tikzAngleOfLine` to the contents of `\tikz@AngleOfLine`.

Even more, this kind of coordinate calculation is handled with the `calc` TikZ library, so you can just load that library and simplify your code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,2) node (yaxis) [above] {$y$}
    |- (3,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
\draw (-1,3) coordinate (a_1) -- (3,0) coordinate (a_2);

\draw[black,->] (a_2) -- ($(a_2)!0.45cm!-90:(a_1)$) node[midway,above,sloped] {$\vec u$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

The coordinate specification `($(a_2)!0.45cm!-90:(a_1)$)` says "start from `a_2`, then move 0.45cm along the line which makes an angle of -90 degrees with the line from `a_2` to `a_1`."  The syntax is dangerously close to [xy-pic](/questions/tagged/xy-pic) level readability, but it's very useful if you know how to read the manual.

Comment: Great! Nice answer!